# Hiccup in code where compiler meets the query

Tags: ms-access, vba

This might be a long shot because I don't think i'm giving enough information but I'll give it a show anyway. I am getting a compiler error saying variable not defined on line with the query. I've tried a few things but I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong..

Still a bit new to VBA so any info would be much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsStepCalendar As DAO.Recordset

        Set rsStepCalendar = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblStepCalendar " & _
                                                "Where (HeaderID = '" & Forms!frmContactsEdit!txtHeader.Value & "' ) " & _
                                                "AND (Cancel = False)" & _
                                                "AND (Active = True)", dbOpenDynaset)

    If rsStepCalendar.EOF Then

        MsgBox ("Add the record")

    Else
        Dim i As Integer

        If chkMonA <> rsStepCalendar("Monday").Value Then
            RstRecSet.Edit
                    rsStepCalendar("Monday").Value = chkMonA.Value
            RstRecSet.Update
        End If

        If chkTuesA <> rsStepCalendar("Tuesday").Value Then
            RstRecSet.Edit
                    rsStepCalendar("Tuesday").Value = chkTuesA.Value
            RstRecSet.Update
        End If

        If chkWedA <> rsStepCalendar("Wednesday").Value Then
            RstRecSet.Edit
                    rsStepCalendar("Wednesday").Value = chkWedA.Value
            RstRecSet.Update
        End If

        If chkThursA <> rsStepCalendar("Thursday").Value Then
            RstRecSet.Edit
                    rsStepCalendar("Thursday").Value = chkThursA.Value
            RstRecSet.Update
        End If

        If chkFriA <> rsStepCalendar("Friday").Value Then
            RstRecSet.Edit
                    rsStepCalendar("Friday").Value = chkFriA.Value
            RstRecSet.Update
        End If

    For i = 0 To 32

            If lstActive.Selected(i) <> rsStepCalendar(i).Value Then
           '     rsStepCalendar(i).Value
            End If
    Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t say where you have this code, but as a general rule, you are missing the start and end of the routine

Eg:

```
Sub MyTest
  ‘ your code goes here
End Sub
```

Next, your code uses DB, but you never set it, so you need this:

```
Sub MyTest()

   Dim db              As DAO.Database
   Dim rsStepCalendar  As DAO.Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb    <--- missing this

Set rsStepCalendar = db.OpenRecordset................
```

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something dumb